# Is using 'gf' in vim with symbolic links possible?

Tags: vim, path, symlink

Is it possible to configure vim to follow symlinks via `gf`?

For example, suppose I have a file `foo.txt` and a symlink `bar` in the same directory. I'd like to be able to edit the file `bar` points to by `gf`'ing over the word 'bar' in `foo.txt`.

More generally, I'd like to be able to use `find` and other path-using commands as though the actual files were in the same directory as the file I'm editing. I'll settle for a working `gf` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. VIM 7.1.

What output do you get when you `gf` over the name of a symlink? Is `+file_in_path` enabled when you type `:version`?

Comment: Works for me (now) also, for some reason rebuilding the link fixed it. Thanks for the good answer, sorry about the stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `:find`, did you configure `&path` ?

Comment: I did not, but it turns out that wasn't the issue in the first place. Probably my fault, and not vim's. Thanks.